# How to login using ssh without any sort of authentication?

Tags: docker, ssh, openssh

I have seen similar questions, but nothing helped.

Like here:

- [SSH login with no authentication](https://serverfault.com/questions/627906/ssh-login-with-no-authentication)
- [SSH session without ANY authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24673155/ssh-session-without-any-authentication)

My problem is as the question states. I want to setup ssh to work without any password prompt or any keys. Means, doing

```
ssh computer@IP_address
```

should give me access to the remote machine.

Question ends here^^^^^^^^^^^. Details of what I'm trying to achieve:

I have a docker image of Ubuntu in which I'm trying to install ssh. This has 2 reasons: easy file transfer using scp and the other is, that I sometimes, by mistake I close docker without committing and end up losing all my progress/data. So I want to make it such that I run the docker container in the background and only access it using ssh. Also, I am working in a team and I'll need to some other outside people(who download my docker image) to be able to work with it easily as well, which is why I want it to be ssh-accessible without a login.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [unix.se] or [su]. When you do, you should explain why the answers on those other two questions weren't helpful.

Comment: `ssh` means Secure Shell, and you want to remove the secure from it and allow anyone to connect to your machine?

Answer (score 1):

You should look at setting  `PermitEmptyPasswords` to `yes` in your `sshd_config` file and restard sshd service.

> PermitEmptyPasswords
>   When password authentication is allowed, it specifies whether the server allows login to accounts with empty password strings. The default is ''no''.

Comment: did you  try restart/reload the ssh  daemon?
ssh with empty password it is a bad idea