# Creating a password-less user to directly log in in SSH

Tags: shell, ssh, raspberry-pi, raspbian

**This is for testing purposes and not for any production system so I understand the attached security risks involved**

I would like to create a user which doesn't have a password. This would be used to do tests on a SSH login method that doesn't require using a password. Just as I type `ssh USER@HOST` I'd log in.

I know this "seamless" login without a password can be done with keys but that's not what I'd like.

I've followed some other questions like [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/how-can-i-deactivate-the-login-password-on-my-raspberry-pi) one without any luck. I've also created another user without a password but I haven't seen a consensus on how to do this.

The results I'm getting is getting locked out of my account as it only requires public key log in or I can't set up a user without a password. Is there any way to do this?

**Solution**: For future reference in case I do stumble upon this again or anyone finds this, [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1080575) worked!

Comment: May I ask _why_ keys are not a solution for you?

Comment: Writing an SSH wrapper and need to test SSH without a password hence the no security risk as this is gonna be tested locally for a brief period of time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to login using ssh without any sort of authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49596760/how-to-login-using-ssh-without-any-sort-of-authentication)

Comment: The problem si that I haven't been able to create a user with an empty password so I'm not certain (yet).

Comment: Whether or not the answers are adequate, (1) the question is clearly a duplicate, and (2) it's not on-topic here regardless (as it's not about writing code; questions about configuring sshd are better fit for [unix.se]).

Comment: ...now, if you did want to have an on-topic Stack Overflow question, try writing an ssh daemon using [Paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/), [go crypto/ssh](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh) or similar, and ask about a specific, narrow problem you encounter in the process.

Comment: For future reference in case I do stumble upon this again or anyone finds this, [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1080575) worked!